# What is the distribution of $\Lambda$?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, maximum-likelihood

> As in [Likelihood ratio test for $H_0:(\mu_1,\mu_2)=(0,0)$ vs $H_1:(\mu_1,\mu_2) \neq (0,0)$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/493478/likelihood-ratio-test-for-h-0-mu-1-mu-2-0-0-vs-h-1-mu-1-mu-2-neq),
> There are $X_1, X_2$ where $X_i \sim N(\mu_i,1), i=1,2$. They are independent. The question is

> Find the likelihood ratio test with $H_0:(\mu_1,\mu_2)=(0,0), H_1:(\mu_1,\mu_2) \neq (0,0)$. The significance level is $\alpha (0< \alpha <1)$ and parameter space $\Omega$ is $$\Omega = \left\{ (\mu_1,\mu_2) : \mu_1 \geq 0, \mu_2 \geq 0\right\}$$

Comment: This looks like it should be `self-study`  https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the distribution of $\Lambda$?

> We have known that $$\Lambda = x_1^2I_{(x_1>0, x_2<0)} + x_2^2I_{(x_1<0, x_2>0)} + (x_1^2+x_2^2)I_{(x_1>0, x_2>0)}$$

You also know the distribution of $x_1$ and $x_2$ when $H_0$ is true. It's a bivariate normal distribution centered at $0,0$ and with variance $I$. Use that to get the distribution of $\Lambda$.

Because of the indicator functions you will get to handle it as a [mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution). In 25% of the cases you get $I_{(x_1>0, x_2<0)} = 1$, in 25% of the cases you get $I_{(x_1<0, x_2>0)} = 1$, in 25% of the cases you get $I_{(x_1>0, x_2>0)} = 1$, and in 25% of the cases $\Lambda = 0$.

Below is an illustration that may help to visualize it. There's $10^4$ points simulated that illustrate the bivariate distribution of $x_1,x_2$. Two example points are drawn with isolines for which the value of $\Lambda$ is constant.

[image: illustration]

So for example the probability that $P(\Lambda \leq 1.92)$ consist of the sum of $$P(\Lambda \leq 1.92) =  
\underbrace{P(x_1<=0,x_2<=0)}_{= 0.25}+
\underbrace{P(x_1>0,x_2<=0 \text{ and } x_1^2 \leq 1.92)}_{= 0.25 \times P(\chi_1^2 <1.92)}+
\underbrace{P(x_1<=0,x_2>0  \text{ and } x_2^2 \leq 1.92 )}_{= 0.25 \times P(\chi_1^2 <1.92)}+
\underbrace{P(x_1>0,x_2>0  \text{ and } x_1^2 + x_2^2 \leq 1.92)}_{= 0.25 \times P(\chi_2^2 <1.92)}  $$

Comment: I think that $X_1^2 \sim \chi_1^2$ and $X_1^2+X_2^2\sim \chi_2^2$? Didn't you use that result?

Comment: I only gave a hint. Indeed you will get some mixture of 50% a $\chi_1^2$, 25% a $\chi_2^2$ distribution (and 25% a point mass).

Comment: Can you write the cdf function $F(x)=P(\Lambda\le x)$ in a formal way? I am not sure what do you mean $25\%$ cases.

Comment: Is this a piecewise function? I mean that $F(x)=0$ as $x_\le 0, x_2\le 0$, $F(x)=\chi_1^2$ as $x_1 \ge 0, x_2\le 0$ or $x_1 \le 0, x_2\ge 0$, and $F(x)=\chi_2^2$ as $x_1 \ge 0, x_2\ge 0$? Is this one right?

Comment: Or just write $F(x)=0.25+0.25P(\chi_1^2\le x)+0.25P(\chi_1^2\le x)+0.25P(\chi_2^2\le x)$?

Comment: The latter one is close but there's two things: **1** you need to consider $x\leq0$ seperately, **2** you can combine two terms $$F(x)=\begin{cases}0.25+0.5P(\chi_1^2\le x)+0.25P(\chi_2^2\le x) &\quad \text{if $x>0$} \\ 0  &\quad \text{if $x\leq 0$} \end{cases}$$

Comment: Check out the link to mixture distributions.

Comment: The idea that you describe in the piecewise function, can be considered as four *conditional* distributions. Given that $x_1>0, x_2>0$ the $\Lambda$ follows a $\chi_2^2$ distribution. And you have four of such conditional distributions that you can combine into one non-conditional distribution by adding the probabilities....

Comment: ... For example say I play some darts and want to express the distribution of my throws over multiple games, but my game is not constant and depends on how much beer I have drunken. Then I have the distribution given 1 pint, the distribution given 2 pints, and so on. If somebody does not know how much I have drunken, but they do know the probabilities for how much pints I have drunken and also the conditional distribution of the dart throws given the number of pints, then they can add everything together by making a weighted sum of the different throwing distributions.